# Can't get grub2 menu to display

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have a laptop which I intend to be dual-boot. It previously booted into Windows (7), and after Linux install now boots directly into Linux (openSUSE). I've edited `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to add the Windows chainloader entry. So far, so good.

Unfortunately I can't get GRUB2 to display the selection menu *at all*, even to select the Safe Mode entry for the Linux install. I get a split-second flash of the "welcome to grub" message and then it boots directly into the default Linux entry.

Things I have tried:

- Setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to an integer value and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` to

  - 0
  - blank
  - commented out
- Setting `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` to both `true` and `false`
- Setting `GRUB_TERMINAL` to `console`
- Removing `quiet` and `splash=silent` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

I am regenerating the config each time with `/usr/sbin/grub2-mkconfig`

Other info:

- Holding shift during boot doesn't bring up the menu regardless of the state of `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT`
- I'm pretty sure this machine isn't using UEFI (I have no `/sys/firmware/efi` directory)
- Legacy USB support is enabled in the BIOS.

Anything else I can try? This is getting really aggravating, I never had this much trouble with grub legacy!

Edit:

Section of `grub.cfg` related to timeout:

```
if [ x${boot_once} = xtrue]; then
    set timeout=0  
elif [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ]; then  
    set timeout_style=menu  
    set timeout=0  
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is unavailable
else  
    set timeout=0  
fi
```

This is different to the output displayed by the grub update script, which has `timeout = 10`! Editing the `grub.cfg` file directly displays the menu as expected.

Comment: What output this command? `grep -i timeout /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: And, on Ubuntu, the `Esc` need to be holded, while booting, in some cases. `Shift` doesn't always work. Try with `Esc` button, may be it will work on OpenSUSE too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do this lines exist in the your `/etc/default/grub`? If not, add them.

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

run `update-grub` afterwards to update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

You can check, if the needed changes has happened, by this way:
`grep -i timeout /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Output should be contained such values:

```
set timeout_style=menu
set timeout=10
```

From the [grub manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration):

> **GRUB_TIMEOUT**
>
> Boot the default entry this many seconds after the menu is displayed,
>   unless a key is pressed. The default is **5**. Set to **0** to boot
>   immediately without displaying the menu, or to **-1** to wait
>   indefinitely. If **GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE** is set to **countdown** or
>   **hidden**, the timeout is instead counted before the menu is displayed.
>
> **GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE**
>
> If this option is unset or set to **menu**, then GRUB will display the
>   menu and then wait for the timeout set by **GRUB_TIMEOUT** to expire
>   before booting the default entry. Pressing a key interrupts the
>   timeout. If this option is set to **countdown** or **hidden**, then,
>   before displaying the menu, GRUB will wait for the timeout set by
>   **GRUB_TIMEOUT** to expire. If **ESC** is pressed during that time, it will display the menu and wait for input. If a hotkey associated with
>   a menu entry is pressed, it will boot the associated menu entry
>   immediately. If the timeout expires before either of these happens, it
>   will boot the default entry. In the **countdown** case, it will show a
>   one-line indication of the remaining time.

Comment: This looked like a really promising lead, as my default grub file had no GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE entry at all, but unfortunately same result as before :( I will try playing with the other values again with this entry added though. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Actually I think you may have put me on the right track asking about the grep output. When I run the update grub script for this OS it outputs what looks like the new contents of grub.cfg, and it has "set timeout=10", but if I grep grub.cfg *itself*, this line is "set timeout=0"! So a bug, possibly...

Answer (score 1):

As you describe, your changes to the `grub` configuration sources do not seem to have an effect. You state that you run `grub2-mkconfig` after each edit. However, if you look at the man-page, you will notice

> `-o, --output=FILE`
>
> output generated config to FILE [default=`stdout`]

As you can see, `grub2-mkconfig` (recently simply `grub-mkconfig`) doesn't write the actual configuration file, it only prints the contents to the console. To make the change become effective, use either

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

or

```
grub-mkonfig > /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```