# GRUB not showing up after Dual Booting Windows 10 and Manjaro. Directly boots to Manjaro

Tags: windows, grub2, uefi, manjaro

I just installed Manjaro on my Windows10 UEFI laptop. I was expecting GRUB to  show up but it directly boots into Manjaro instead. When I tried `sudo update-grub`. It shows this:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/manjaro/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8-x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.8-x86_64.img
Found initrd fallback image: /boot/initramfs-5.8-x86_64-fallback.img
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+/memtest.bin
done
```

I am not sure what the problem is. But I've seen that it says `Found linux image` twice in YouTube vids. I think I used the wrong partition to install GRUB. But this is just a guess as I'm a noob myself. Any solutions guys? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get grub2 menu to display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373402/cant-get-grub2-menu-to-display)

Comment: As shown in link above by Freddy, this is the important setting in /etc/default/grub: `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` But with UEFI, you should always be able to boot any install directly from UEFI boot menu. And grub only boots working Windows. So when Windows turns fast start up back on with an update, you will have to directly boot Windows from UEFI.